# dedup function not returning the expected output

Tags: rust

I'm trying to eliminate duplicates in a sorted vector with the dedup function, but it returns empty.

Here's my code:

```
fn main() {
    let mut input = vec![1, 1, 2, 3, 3];
    remove_dup(&mut input);
}

fn remove_dup(input: &mut Vec<u32>) { 
    let result = input.dedup(); 
    println!("Result: {:?}", result);
}
```

Here's the output:

```
Result: ()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `dedup()` method operates in-place, updating the original vector.

```rust
fn main() {
    let mut input = vec![1, 1, 2, 3, 3];
    remove_dup(&mut input);
}

fn remove_dup(input: &mut Vec<u32>) { 
    input.dedup(); 
    println!("Result: {:?}", input);
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=431e6550e14758f7c6c86b598d8eebde).

In general, when you see a function that returns `()` (no return type), it's a good sign that it's a modifying operation.